# Anyway to directly access a IPv4 port?

Tags: networking, dns, server, ip, port

I've a VPS with IPv6 and a IPv4 NAT - so I have access to the server through IPv4 with a port range for my service.

The ideal use for the server would be a mail server and DNS records (specifically MX records) cannot take a port.

Is there anyway to access this server without having to declare the port, for example through a domain like example.com being mapped to 192.168.1.1:200?

Comment: No.  Machines are identified by addresses.  Only particular services on a machine are identified by ports.  If you have a machine inside a NATed network that you want to use to provide services to external machines, then you need your NAT to support you.  It must either provide a distinct external address for the server machine, or it must itself proxy for the service.

Answer (score 1):

IP does know nothing about "ports". It is a network layer protocol that is responsible for addressing and routing. Look closer to OSI model, for example here: [OSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)

Any service you run is situated above this layer. It hard to understand what do you mean under "access the server"? If you think about SSH or RDP -- you can't reach them without port definition. If you think about exchanging information between client and server without specifing the port -- it is possible. For example by using ICMP for data exchange though it is not meant for that.

Answer (score 0):

Every service need a port.
DNS need to run under a port 53(or not)..
MX record is not a service.

You need to know what is a service and the relation of a service and ports